# Linear Regression of Subset depending on spesific date

Tags: regression, subset

I'm currently doing a regression analysis for every company on the Norwegian Stock Market, where i regress the stockreturns for each company against a benchmark. The period is 2009-2018. I've managed to do the regression for each company throughout the whole period, but i also want to do a regression for each month for every company.

The original dataset consists of 26000 observations, which i've then converted into subsets with a total of 390 elements(companies).

What i've done so far is shown below:

```
data_subset <- by(data,data$Name, subset)
data_lm <-lapply(data_subset,function(data) lm(data$CompanyReturn~data$DJReturn))

  data_coef <- lapply(data_lm, coef)
  data_tabell <- matrix(0,length(data_subset),2)
for (i in 1:length(data_subset)) {
  data_tabell[i,]<-coef(data_lm[[i]])
}
colnames(data_tabell)<-c("Intercept","Coefficient")
rownames(data_tabell)<-names(data_subset)
```

Do anyone know how i can specify that i want to only do a regression for a company for a specific period, for example each year or each month for every company?

Thank you in advance for the help!